# Creating Height Responsive Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm creating a Worldle clone and am trying to figure out how to get my word grid and its box elements to shrink in response to the change in height of the window. I tried messing around with different flex properties instead of using grid, but nothing seemed to get me the outcome I was looking for.

You can see the effect I am looking to recreate [here](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) by messing with the height of your window.

This is the css code I have now, where grid is reference to the grid containing the box elements.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 30px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 30px);
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
```

Comment: The link that you posted links to stackoverflow.com, you can't see anything there. Please correct it.

Comment: You can use interactive HTML/CSS snippets on StackOverflow.  It will help others see live results of your code and experiment with it.